# jquery length and enumeration (count out into string)

Tags: jquery, arrays, count

I have an array that I need to covert to a simple sequence, and then count it out.

Ex:

```
var real_array = [1980, 1985, 1987, 1990, 1992]

real_array.length; //5
```

How would I output and enumerate the length in numbers?

Ex:

```
$('.count').text(somefunction);

<span class="label">result:</span><span class="count"></span>

result: 1,2,3,4,5
```

Edit: here is a really simpe fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h829eprr/1/

Comment: `[1980, 1985, 1987, 1990, 1992].map( (v, i) => i + 1)`

Comment: Let me see if I understand: you need to know the length of the numbers inside the array? Could you provide some Fiddle?

Comment: I think I need to use while, see here https://jsfiddle.net/h829eprr/1/

Comment: I don't what you want, but you can try: `[1980, 1985, 1987, 1990, 1992].reduce((p, a, i) =>  (i > 1) ? p + (',' + i) : '1')`

Comment: If What you need is to enumerate the elements `[10,20,30,40]` so the out put is `result: 1,2,3,4`? that is a simple for on `real_array.length` like: `for(idx=1; idx<=real_array.length; idx++){ if(idx = real_array.length) {enum += idx;} else {enum += idx+", ";}}`

Comment: You mean like this https://jsfiddle.net/h829eprr/4/ ?